# Usage of "improve."

Tags: meaning, phrases, verbs, context

I recently read a WikiHow article, How to Be a Hard Worker, where I encountered the following usage of the verb "improve":

"Maximize potential and
improve weaknesses." —WikiHow

Is the phrase "improve weaknesses" grammatical? If yes, then I have a doubt, as it says to improve (making it even more better) weaknesses. Doesn't it mean to further enhance the weaknesses?

The verb "improve" generally means to make or cause to make something better.

If I use this verb (improve) in the following conversation, what would be your comments and answers?

Henry: Hi John, how are you and how is your health?

John: I'm Fine. My health improved much as compared to the previous year. [here the John's health improved a lot, which was already little improved in the previous year].

So I think using "improve weaknesses" mean to enhance it further.

Answer (score 1):

"Improve weaknesses" may be a grammatically correct structure but in that context it sounds wrong; like someone has missed out a word, "upon" for example. I have seen the phrase "improve upon your weaknesses" it is both grammatically correct and conveys the meaning I would expect that the sentence *should* have given the context.

Comment: Then which verb to use in place of 'improve'?

Comment: "Work on" or possibly "strengthen".